# Customised doc generation in Javadoc using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc, build.gradle

I have many test cases written in a JAVA file.
I need to generate separate docs based on **groups** like:

> @Test(groups = { Constant.UT_POSITIVE } **OR**
>   @Test(groups = { Constant.UT_NEGATIVE }

So, below two test cases should move to two different java docs based on **groups**

> **Any help will be appreciated**

```
/**
 * TESTCASE for successful GET of user.
 *
 * @throws Exception In case of exception scenario
 * @ExpectedResponseCode 200 ( Successful Retrieval )
 */

@Test(groups = { Constant.UT_POSITIVE })
public void testGetUserSuccess() throws Exception {
    mockValidateUser();
    MockCUserDAOImpl.getResponseCode = Constant.RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS_DB_GET;
    getResponse = testConsumer
            .getUser(
                    CONSUMER_GUID, CUSTOMER_GUID, AUTHORIZATION);
    Assert.assertEquals(getResponse.getStatus(),
            Constant.RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS);
}


 /**
 * TESTCASE for failed GET of user.
 *
 * @throws Exception In case of exception scenario
 * @ExpectedResponseCode 400 ( failed Retrieval )
 */

@Test(groups = { Constant.UT_NEGATIVE})
public void testGetUserSuccess() throws Exception {
    mockValidateUser();
    MockCUserDAOImpl.getResponseCode = Constant.RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS_DB_GET;
    getResponse = testConsumer
            .getUser(
                    CONSUMER_GUID, CUSTOMER_GUID, AUTHORIZATION);
    Assert.assertEquals(getResponse.getStatus(),
            Constant.RESPONSE_CODE_SUCCESS);
}
```